# matplotlib fixed size when dragging RectangleSelector

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I click the center of `RectangleSelector` and drag it to the edges of `axes`, the **width** or **height** will be changed (become smaller). This behavior is different from `EllipseSelector` whose **width** and **height** don't be changed and can be dragged outside current `axes` view. So how can keep `RectangleSelector` size when dragging?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easier way to fix this behavior, but you could create a custom `RectangleSelector` overriding the `_onmove` method to make sure the rectangle X position (respectively Y position) is updated only when the width (respectively the height) do not change.

```py
class CustomRectangleSelector(RectangleSelector):
    
    def _onmove(self, event):
        # Start bbox
        s_x0, s_x1, s_y0, s_y1 = self.extents
        start_width = np.float16(s_x1 - s_x0)
        start_height = np.float16(s_y1 - s_y0)
        
        super()._onmove(event)
        
        # Custom behavior only if selector is moving
        if not self._active_handle == 'C':  
            return
        
        # End bbox
        e_x0, e_x1, e_y0, e_y1 = self.extents
        end_width = np.float16(e_x1 - e_x0)
        end_height = np.float16(e_y1 - e_y0)

        if start_width != end_width:
            e_x0, e_x1 = s_x0, s_x1
            
        if start_height != end_height:
            e_y0, e_y1 = s_y0, s_y1
            
        self.extents = e_x0, e_x1, e_y0, e_y1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @thmslmr. I finally achieved the goal by override `_draw_shape`.

class CustomRectangleSelector(RectangleSelector):

```
def _draw_shape(self, extents):
    x0, x1, y0, y1 = extents
    xmin, xmax = sorted([x0, x1])
    ymin, ymax = sorted([y0, y1])
    
    # DO NOT apply the xy limits
    #xlim = sorted(self.ax.get_xlim())
    #ylim = sorted(self.ax.get_ylim())

    #xmin = max(xlim[0], xmin)
    #ymin = max(ylim[0], ymin)
    #xmax = min(xmax, xlim[1])
    #ymax = min(ymax, ylim[1])

    self._selection_artist.set_x(xmin)
    self._selection_artist.set_y(ymin)
    self._selection_artist.set_width(xmax - xmin)
    self._selection_artist.set_height(ymax - ymin)
    self._selection_artist.set_angle(self.rotation)
```